# Как справиться с этой ошибкой? версия node 8.0.0

Tags: node.js, npm

```
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
npm ERR! weird error 8
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Не ваш случай? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168141/cannot-install-packages-using-node-package-manager-in-ubuntu  Если вкратце то в некоторых дистрибутивах интерпретатор ноды называется не node а nodejs и надо слегка побить в бубен чтобы он работал из коробки

Comment: Также убедитесь что ваша ide втихую не ставит внутри себя свой инстанс ноды более старой версии. Вижуал студия под виндой например так делает частенько

Comment: `node -v` наверняка выведет не 8ю версию.

Answer (score 1):

Эта ошибка срабатывает когда вы используете const вне строгого окружёния, вне 'use strict'. В тексте ошибки прямо советуют включить строгий режим. Однако в 8 версии ноды этой ошибки быть точно не должно. Проверьте версию ноды, которую используете. Я всегда ставил ноду с их сайта в папку пользователя $home/bin, это если для личного использования. На сервере же вы просто можете запустить ноду в докере.